# Excel formula to search column for specific text then list offset cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I don’t have m365 so textjoin and filter won’t work for me

I want to look through a column to find all instances of todays date, then return a list of comma separated values in an offset column

I’d rather use a formula and not a macro

[image]

Comment: Which version of Excel do you use? Do you have Power query available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without Textjoin and Filter function, you need helper column to join the result, please see below.

1] In "Criteria" `A14`, enter the date

2] In "Helper" `C2`, enter formula and copied down :

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(TEXT(A$14,"dd/m/yyyy"),B2)),A2&IFERROR(", "&INDEX(C3:C$11,MATCH("*"&TEXT(A$14,"dd/m/yyyy")&"*",B3:B$11,0)),""),"")
```

3] In "Result" `B14`, enter formula :

```
=VLOOKUP("*"&TEXT(A$14,"dd/m/yyyy")&"*",B2:C11,2,0)
```

[image]